# Cannot await 'Void' even when using Task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, void

I have a problem. I am trying to modify an app I made some time ago and it Works still on WP Phone, but now I try to run it get these errors:

On await I get:

> cannot await 'void'.

When I change void to task the error is still

> Cannot await 'void'

I don't even have `void` any more.

Can somebody help me ?

```
namespace StreamUploadDownload
{
    using System.Threading;
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private PhotoCamera _cam;
        private double _canvasWidth;
        private double _canvasHeight;
        private MediaLibrary _library = new MediaLibrary();
        public int count = 100;
        private static readonly string[] scopes = new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.offline_access", "wl.skydrive_update", "wl.skydrive" };
        string comboValue;
        private LiveConnectClient liveClient;
        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 0;  

        public string FileText { get; set; }
        public int ComboNumber { get; set; }
        public int ConnectionOK { get; set; }

        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        private void OnSessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.liveClient = (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected) ? new LiveConnectClient(e.Session) : null;
            if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                btnSignin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Pildista.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                //Pildista2K.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Pildista.Content = "Pildista";    
            }
            else
            {
                Pildista.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                //Pildista2K.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btnSignin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }    

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true) ||
                 (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true))
            {
                if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary))
                {
                    _cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
                    _cam.Initialized += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(cam_Initialized);
                    _cam.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureImageAvailable);
                    viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_cam);

                    //CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += OnButtonFullPress;

                    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
                    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("Text"))
                    {
                        txtvalue.Text = (string)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Text"];
                        FileText = txtvalue.Text;
                    }
                    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("index"))
                    {
                        ComboNumber = (int)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["index"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // The camera is not supported on the device.
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                        {
                            // Write message.    
                        });

                        // Disable UI.    
                        AFButton.IsEnabled = false;    
                    }    
                }
            }
        }

        private double GetCameraAspectRatio()
        {
            IEnumerable<Size> resList = _cam.AvailableResolutions;

            if (resList.Count<Size>() > 0)
            {
                Size res = resList.ElementAt<Size>(0);
                return res.Width / res.Height;
            }

            return 1;
        }

        void cam_Initialized(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Succeeded)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    _canvasHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
                    _canvasWidth = _canvasHeight * GetCameraAspectRatio();

                    viewfinderCanvas.Width = _canvasWidth;
                    viewfinderCanvas.Height = _canvasHeight;
                });
            }
        }   

        //Failinime andmine ning salvestamine.
        private async void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ComboNumber == 1)
            {
                comboValue = "O";
            }
            if (ComboNumber == 2)
            {
                comboValue = "T";
            }
            if (ComboNumber == 3)
            {
                comboValue = "S";
            }
            if (ComboNumber == 4)
            {
                comboValue = "P";
            }
            if (ComboNumber == 5)
            {
                comboValue = "A";
            }
            if (ComboNumber == 6)
            {
                comboValue = "M";
            }

            string fileName = String.Format(FileText + "_" + comboValue + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".jpg");    

            try
            {    
                LiveOperationResult operationResult = await this.liveClient.UploadAsync("/me/skydrive", fileName, e.ImageStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite); //Cannot await 'void'    
            }

            catch (LiveConnectException ex)
            {
                // e.ImageStream.Close();
                // this.infoTextBlock.Text = "Error getting contact info: ";
                // this.infoTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;    
            }
            finally
            {    
                e.ImageStream.Close();
                y++;
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    string b = Convert.ToString(y);
                    loobvalue2.Text = b;
                });    
            }    
        }    

        //kaameranupu vajutus.

        private void takephoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {    
            if (_cam != null)
            {    
                _cam.CaptureImage();
                x++;
                string s = x.ToString();
                loobvalue.Text = s;    
            }    
        }   

        // Ühenduse Loomine. Session load.
        private async void connectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool connected = false;
            try
            {
                var authClient = new LiveAuthClient("RemovedforWeb");
                LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive" }); // cannot await 'void'

                if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    connected = true;
                    var connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
                    var meResult = await connectClient.GetAsync("me");
                    dynamic meData = meResult.Result; //cannot await 'void'
                    }
                else
                {
                    //btnSignin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }    
            }
            catch (LiveAuthException ex)
            {

            }
```

EDIT: I added more code, and commented on problematic places

Comment: You have tow awaits, one for `authClient.LoginAsync` and one for `connectClient.GetAsync`. These are supposed to return `Task<LiveLoginResult>` and `Task<T>` where T is the type of `meResult`. Does any of them return `void` or `Task`?

Comment: What line of code are you talking about?

Comment: Your error is in another castle. Please show the rest of the code and the full error message with stack trace.

Comment: @MariusBancila When he'd have Task as return type for one of these methods the error message would be like 'Cannot convert type void to LiveLoginResult or whatever meResult should be. So if the error is really in that piece of code, it must be that `authClient.LoginAsync` or `connectClient.GetAsync` are of type void.

Comment: Too much code. Please keep it [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This line is incorrect: `meResult.Result`. `await` already unwind the result from the task, so you should use directly `meResult`. What is the signature of `connectClient.GetAsync` method?

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht that's what I'm saying too

Comment: You say "I don't even have `void` any more", yet almost all of your functions have a `void` return type...

Answer (score 7):

```
public async Task Method1 ()
{

}

public async Task<int> Method2 ()
{

}
```

For the above code, "Method1" does not return any value, whereas "Method2" returns an "int" value.

```
int i = await Method2(); //this is correct
await Method2(); //this is correct
int i = await Method1(); //this is NOT correct
await Method1(); //this is also correct
```

For the following line of code

```
LiveOperationResult operationResult = await this.liveClient.UploadAsync("/me/skydrive", fileName, e.ImageStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite); //Cannot await 'void'
```

The "UploadAsync" method does not return any value, that's what it seems if you say "Cannot await 'void'"

Try removing "LiveOperationResult operationResult =" from the line of code and just write -

```
await this.liveClient.UploadAsync("/me/skydrive", fileName, e.ImageStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

Same for the second line of code-

```
LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive" }); // cannot await 'void'
```

Re-Write it as-

```
await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive" }); // cannot await 'void'
```

Comment: The first method perfectly replaces `void`.